# MonoDevelop is not working (xterm is installed)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono

I recently installed elementary OS Luna. We have C# lessons in our school, so I wanted to use Mono and MonoDevelop.

I have added directhex/monoxide PPA repository and then I installed Mono with "sudo apt-get install mono".

**mono -V returns this:**

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.1 (Debian 3.2.1+dfsg-1~pre2)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

Then, I have installed MonoDevelop, with command "sudo apt-get install monodevelop", I have version 3.0.1. Then, I have installed xterm, with "sudo apt-get install xterm".

My MonoDevelop is running properly, until I want to run my application.

When I use F5 or Ctrl+F5, it returns this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: File name has not been set
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.ProcessWrapper.Start () [0x00006] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core.Execution/ProcessWrapper.cs:27 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.ProcessWrapper:Start ()
  at MonoDevelop.Platform.GnomePlatform.StartConsoleProcess (System.String command, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, System.String title, Boolean pauseWhenFinished) [0x00090] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/addins/GnomePlatform/GnomePlatform.cs:219 
  at MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.ProcessService.StartConsoleProcess (System.String command, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, IConsole console, System.EventHandler exited) [0x000e5] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core.Execution/ProcessService.cs:211 
  at MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.SoftDebuggerEngine+<CreateDebuggerStartInfo>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__6 (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info) [0x00000] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/SoftDebuggerEngine.cs:84 
  at Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachineManager.BeginLaunch (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info, System.AsyncCallback callback, Mono.Debugger.Soft.LaunchOptions options) [0x00139] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/contrib/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/VirtualMachineManager.cs:101 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.StartLaunching (Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerStartInfo dsi) [0x001d2] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugging.Soft/SoftDebuggerSession.cs:209 
  at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.OnRun (Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerStartInfo startInfo) [0x0002d] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugging.Soft/SoftDebuggerSession.cs:111 
  at Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerSession+<Run>c__AnonStorey6.<>m__3 () [0x00000] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/core/Mono.Debugging/Mono.Debugging.Client/DebuggerSession.cs:306
```

I really would like to use Linux at school, but this error is forcing me back to Windows, help me please :(.

Also, sorry for my english, it's not my native language. Thanks for help.

Comment: You are recommended to use Mono 3 on Windows or Mac along with Xamarin Studio. So far I find using it on Linux frustrating, as I have to build Mono from source, as well as MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop 3 is some years old. Please upgrade to MonoDevelop 4.x